# How to make an object rotate around the exact center of the screen using animateTransform?

Tags: animation, svg, units-of-measurement, smil

Consider the following SVG code for moving a circle around the center of the screen, with hard-coded dimensions:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g>
        <ellipse id="circ" style="fill:#000000"
            cx="60%" cy="50%"
            rx="10" ry="10" />

        <!--Assuming window size is 1000x1000-->    
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
            type="rotate" dur="10s"
            from="0,500,500"
            to="360,500,500"
            repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

If I try to provide the center of rotation in percent, the animation doesn't work at all:

```
<animateTransform attributeName="transform"
    type="rotate" dur="10s"
    from="0,50%,50%"
    to="360,50%,50%"
    repeatCount="indefinite"/>
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Set a `viewBox` on your SVG, then whatever size you make it, the ellipse will rotate around the centre of it.

```
viewBox="0 0 1000 1000"
```

The value of 1000 for width and height here is chosen because it would make 500 be the centre.

```css
svg:nth-child(1) {
  width: 200px;
}

svg:nth-child(2) {
  width: 500px;
}

svg {
  border: solid 1px green;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
    <g>
        <ellipse id="circ" style="fill:#000000"
            cx="60%" cy="50%"
            rx="10" ry="10" />

        <!--Assuming window size is 1000x1000-->    
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
            type="rotate" dur="10s"
            from="0,500,500"
            to="360,500,500"
            repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </g>
</svg>

<!-- An exact duplicate of th first one -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
    <g>
        <ellipse id="circ" style="fill:#000000"
            cx="60%" cy="50%"
            rx="10" ry="10" />

        <!--Assuming window size is 1000x1000-->    
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
            type="rotate" dur="10s"
            from="0,500,500"
            to="360,500,500"
            repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```